# Creating an alert function in Bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I wanted to create a function in bash similar to a default alias I got in Ubuntu, looking like:

```
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
```

This creates a simple notification after a command has been issued with it.
For example, using

```
history | grep vim; sleep 5; alert
```

gives a notification after the sleep is done, simply saying

```
history | grep vim; sleep 5;
```

I would like to write the alert into a bash function instead, which have given some trouble with the regex.
I have  tried:

```
function alert2 () {
    ICON=$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)
    MSG=$(history | tail -n1 | sed -e s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//\;s/[\;\&\|]\s*alert$//)
    notify-send --urgency=low -i $ICON $MSG
}
```

which would output both the linenumber in `history` when called itself, and give an `Invalid number of options` when called such as the first example.
Is this possible, and if so, how? Is it simply my  regex that is faulty?

Comment: You need single quotes around that sed script just as in your alias.

Comment: That tag was added by OP, also we all know what is `/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//\;s/[\;\&\|]\s*alert$/` in question. Tags are used to enhance easy search for a question later by others. Completely unrelated tags should not be used but somewhat related tags do have their use cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm running on WSL, so don't have `notify-send` installed:

```
function alert2 () {
  ICON=$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error);
  MSG=$(history | tail -n1| sed -e 's/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert2$//');
  echo $ICON $MSG;
}

jadams@Temp046317:~/code/data-extract$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list > /dev/null ; alert2
terminal cat /etc/apt/sources.list > /dev/null
```

I'm hoping that this would work for you (instead of the `echo`):

```
notify-send --urgency=low -i "$ICON $MSG"
```

Comment: Well, it now creates the correct string. Unfortunately it still reports the error "Invalid number of options" when calling `sleep 1; alert2` (I think I need to get more familiar with Bash functions..)

Comment: weirdly, it worked for me (with the `echo`): `jadams@Temp046317:~/code/data-extract$ sleep 1 ; alert2
terminal sleep 1` ... did you add the quotes about the `$ICON $MSG` as per my example?

Comment: Well damn, I forgot that.. Thanks for the answer, it now works perfectly !